# Как увеличить регистр конкретной буквы в массиве C#

Tags: c#, массивы, for

Уважаемые C# не злитесь пожалуйста за такие вопросы, меня просто интересует как увеличить конкретную  букву в массиве? Моя попытка это сделать на JS

```
 let a=["asov", "syz", "io", "fpz"];

x=a.map(re=>{arr=[...re];
 try{
 arr[2]=arr[2].toUpperCase(); return arr.join('')} catch {
   console.log("Erroz");
 }
 })
console.log(x.join(' '))
```

Comment: Лучше покажите вашу попытку сделать это на C#

Comment: Но учусь не будьте ко мне так  жестоки (((

Comment: [Строки (Руководство по программированию на C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/)

Comment: Сейчас мне это не поможет, экспериментирую пока

Comment: Если вам не поможет документация, содержащая ответ на ваш вопрос, боюсь вам вряд-ли что-то еще поможет изучить C#, в том числе даже если вы получите здесь готовый ответ.

Comment: arr[2].ToUpper();

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk я вам открою маленький секрет, но метод `char.ToUpper` является статическим; т. е. вот такое решение будет верным: `arr[2] = char.ToUpper(arr[2])`

Comment: @return спасибо, не подумал, что там char будет, а не string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не претендую на истину в последней инстанции, т.к. в Linq не силён, но Вашу проблему решает:

```cs
int idx = 2;

var items = new string[]{
  "abc", "abcdefg", "hi", null, ""
};

var newItems = items
    .Where(x => (x?.Length ?? -1) > idx)
    .Select(y => y.Substring(0, idx) +
        char.ToUpper(y[idx]) +
        (y.Length > idx + 1 ? y.Substring(idx + 1) : "")
    );

/* Более "читабельный" вариант

var newItems = new List<string>();

foreach(string item in items)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item) && item.Length > idx)
    {
        string res = item.Substring(0, idx);
        res += char.ToUpper(item[idx]);
        if (item.Length > idx + 1)
        {
            res += item.Substring(idx + 1);
        }
        newItems.Add(res);
    }
}
*/

string str = string.Join(", ", newItems);

Console.WriteLine(str);
// abC, abCdefg
```

"Поиграться" можно [здесь](https://repl.it/@XelaNimed/ConvertCharWithSpecifiedIdxToUpperCase).

Comment: Спасибо за пример, я практический везде понял код, кроме этой части **.Where(x => (x?.Length ?? -1) > idx)
    .Select(y => y.Substring(0, idx) +
        char.ToUpper(y[idx]) +
        (y.Length > idx + 1 ? y.Substring(idx + 1) : "")
    );**  Можно ее более читально написать, с примением операторов if ?

Comment: @Грустьжизни обновил. Но если Вы только делаете первые шаги в C#, то Вам стоит непременно освоить [LINQ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query).

Answer (score 0):

Как бы я это сделал не через LINQ, с помощью StringBuilder:

```
private static string[] MakeCapitalLetterForAllStringsInArrayAtIndex(string[] items, int index)
{
    if (items == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (index < 0)
    {
        var itemsCopy = new string[items.Length];
        items.CopyTo(itemsCopy, 0);

        return itemsCopy;
    }

    var newItems = new string[items.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        newItems[i] = MakeCapitalLetterAtIndex(items[i], index);
    }
    
    // Либо вместо цикла
    // var newItems = items.Select(i => MakeCapitalLetterAtIndex(i, index)).ToArray();

    return newItems;
}

private static string MakeCapitalLetterAtIndex(string item, int index)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var sb = new StringBuilder(item);

    if (index < sb.Length)
    {
        sb[index] = char.ToUpper(sb[index]);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Пример в использования в консоли:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var items = new string[] { "asov", "syz", string.Empty, "io", null, "fpz"};
    const int index = 1;

    PrintStringArray(items, "Before: ");

    var newItems = MakeCapitalLetterForAllStringsInArrayAtIndex(items, index);

    PrintStringArray(newItems, "After: ");
    ;
}

private static void PrintStringArray(string[] items, string title)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"==============={title}==============================");
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("======================================================");
}
```

Comment: Честно,  хотелось более компактный и читабельный код( это я наверно после ruby плохо понимаю (

Comment: @Грустьжизни забавно. Когда вам в ответе выше написали короткую версию, вы сказали "непонятно, нужно с операторами if". Вот я и предложил решение не в функциональном стиле. Если вы хотите писать программы в функциональном стиле, может, вам не нужно изучать C#, а перейти на какую-нибудь Scala?

Comment: Мне этот код более понятный, чем выше другие let a=["asov", "syz", "io", "fpz"];

x=a.map(re=>{arr=[...re];
 try{
 arr[2]=arr[2].toUpperCase(); return arr.join('')} catch {
   console.log("Erroz");
 }
 })
console.log(x.join(' '))